# How to have an interface contain sub-types while also being a valid type by itself

Tags: typescript, types, interface, namespaces, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a namespace/class/interface/type (whichever I need, I've researched all of them and none seem to be able to fulfill what I need), which has some **properties** and **methods** typing declared. But also have subtypes within it like `Character.Stats` or `Character.Currency`. **While still having *just* `Character` as a valid type**

How would I need to format/layout my typing file to allow this `classes.ts` file to be valid typescript?

```
// statement to import Character type

class Player implements Character {
    constructor (
        public name: string, // a property
        public stats: Character.Stats, // a property with a subtype typing
        public currency: Character.Currency
    ) {
        this.name = name
        this.stats = stats
        this.currency = currency
    }

    attack(target: Player) { // parameter is typing of its own class
        console.log(`Attacked ${Character.name}`)
    }
}
```

Is this even currently possible with typescript?

Below is my current test codebase:

`types/items.ts`

```
export interface Type {
    name: string,
    sprite: string,
}
```

`types/characters.ts`

```
import * as Classes from "../classes";

export interface Stats {
    health: number,
    attack: number,
    defence: number,
}

export interface Currency {
    gold: number,
    ridium: number
}

export interface Type {
    name: string,
    stats: Stats
    currency: Currency

    announce(sentence: string): void,
    attack(target: Type): void,
    heal(item: Classes.HealingItem): void

}
```

`classes.ts`

```
import * as Characters from "./types/characters";
import * as Items from "./types/items"

export class Character implements Characters.Type {

    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public stats: Characters.Stats,
        public currency: Characters.Currency
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.stats = stats
        this.currency = currency
    }

    announce(sentence: string) {
        console.log(`I, ${this.name}, ${sentence}`)
    }

    attack(target: Character): void {
        this.announce(`am going to attack ${target.name}`)
    }

    heal(item: HealingItem) {
        this.stats.health += item.healthPoints;
        this.announce(`used ${item.name} to heal my hp from ${this.stats.health - item.healthPoints} to ${this.stats.health}`)
    }

}

export class HealingItem implements Items.Type {

    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public sprite: string,
        public healthPoints: number
    ) {
        this.name = name
        this.sprite = sprite
        this.healthPoints = healthPoints
    }

}
```

`index.ts`

```
import * as Classes from "./classes";

const hero = new Classes.Character("Bob", // name
    { // stats
        health: 100,
        attack: 10,
        defence: 25
    },
    { // currency
        gold: 50,
        ridium: 0
    }
)

const apple = new Classes.HealingItem("Apple", "./sprites/apple.sprite", 25);

hero.heal(apple);
hero.attack(hero);
```

This current code all works fine, but it seems like this current layout will cause issues in the future. Due to the `Items.Type`/`Characters.Type`

If this is the closest I can get to the result I would like, then...

In short...

I would like something like this

```
interface B {
    x: string
}

namespace A {
    export type v1 = number
    export type v2 = boolean
    export type v3 = B
}

let p: A = {
    v1: 9,
    v2: true,
    v3: { x: "some string" }
};
let q: A.v1 = 2;
let r: A.v2 = false;
let s: A.v3 = { x: "strung" };
```

This is not valid code as `let p: A` doesn't allow a namespace as a type, but hopefully this portrays what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: How would one go about constructing a `Character.Stats` in your mind? What is the point of this special type if not to type values?  Knowing more about your use case will help determine what the solution should look like.

Comment: Ok, Ive uploaded the code I have currently.
All types are stored in `./types` directory which are imported from the `classes.ts` which creates some classes uses the `implements` keyword then exports those classes to be uses in `index.ts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to be able to get rid of the `.Type` suffix, so that you could write directly:

```
class Character implements Characters {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public stats: Characters.Stats, // Type as a "member" of Characters
    public currency: Characters.Currency
  ) {}
  // Etc.
}
```

You are puzzled because you do not see how to "embed" `Stats` and `Currency` types as "members" of `Characters`.

On the one hand, if it were an `interface`, any "embedded" type would be seen as a member of the interface as well.

On the other hand, if it were a `namespace`, it could not be used directly as a type itself.

You can actually achieve *both at the same time*, because `namespace` enables [*merging*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes-functions-and-enums) into other types.

With this, we declare the `interface`, and we *merge* it with a `namespace` *using the same name*.

```
export interface Characters {
    name: string
    stats: Characters.Stats
    currency: Characters.Currency

    announce(sentence: string): void
    attack(target: Characters): void
    heal(item: HealingItem): void
}

// Merge the namespace with the type of the same name
namespace Characters {
    // Make sure the "embedded" types are explicitly exported
    export interface Stats {
        health: number
        attack: number
        defence: number
    }
    export interface Currency {
        gold: number
        ridium: number
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQAtModUoBnOAbwCg4G4lMBbYALjgpimQHN6jbphgVOREmTQUAdAGUYIioIbYArlCjAk2AJ7jipbOVn4NWnbtoq4mJEghqdwABQVtqZ5268kfAJScAG4QCAAmNiKK2ADWLopQfMAwBpLG0oFwIeE2hMCYADYuCKgsnAAS+QX8AJKlmdkRAL7WAPStcACyaElwMHlMrMAUYDh4AO4lhH0DMLpgeBDoM3gUQ4NstMxsI2MEhlKUNDbtXZgxqxp4-XgARMAsAEbAYWEvt33zw7ZacKBg1WwJQKuj+4GgqAijDBkFgiBQaCwuDgCiUx2h0LyhX6nCQaieaBs0KiOBiuPxzygRMYb3Q2lw5IJVOhLWh-wh8PISLwZk09NBdAxjD4EAKYUZlOpDF4YQQ+IlhJZtBatGwBUwFCoEiM5EQLABDw8WoO6SOgsY2AgSB8amM0BcUrgYDUj0BGw4XB4-AANI7na6ENhPUpUjrpPJFKJfUKGP63eo+ZZQ4dTOZ+TZ-DQ4CrifZHM43B56R6fPxM+ahZbraLgDIChA+C4AAY1b1wAAk1H6CFk22ATTbnfcCOcTSb-hsOcYJNi8RISRS+zS5AaoTC6Jj3dkdgcTlwzdYcBF-D6EFsMGiMQ7XfnyRkfbHE6VuSqxVKFSqtXqG6FW5kwlEGQsQKfo4AAagAXkQUogKqfoAAVQhQCgAG5HT-Hd833Js1HcddOxKB57yGJpTzgYC4BYUFCDAOB0CgCAWGvP8ANkYDQIAWmgoj2MIRDkFEUiYDPTsWMjNi4MIR9J2Vax2ThATET2OoHioCt3W8L0-BsEZeFQTTfAEFU1Q1KhKkKL8Hj1A02GQuAVJYNSbCrG07SgB0YydF03T7AyfT9bzAy4MA9JLLS+GjGM4yC3j+OQhVmUYcts1k1UrW4ci0DPKCkGAcYlzDdzbgAIQgR5bjbU4+xsag4FOVjHV4zgAEYAAZWsioUZzJOA2s6jFaWLTgACYAFZJ362rTgTCw9EdEUxU4UaOsdGU5TKOBWpkic0uteBMDAA04ByvK4HM6o-AclxbgAQUOgpgAquBbhkVpdMIihWgOg1-xCwinrG-w0NoPIGNgwoXG+h6gZBrKZG6lxQYgGGgA)

---

BTW, in your constructor, you do not need to explicitly assign your class members if they are already used as constructor parameters with the same name and a visibility modifier, see [Class Parameter Properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties):

> TypeScript offers special syntax for turning a constructor parameter into a class property with the same name and value. These are called *parameter properties* and are created by prefixing a constructor argument with one of the visibility modifiers `public`, `private`, `protected`, or `readonly`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the detailed answer, I knew there was a better way to do this. I saw something about how declaring the same interface would combine them but I never thought of using that idea for namespaces **and** interfaces together. Thank you again

Comment: Also thank you for the tip on class property declaration, I'll do some more reading into this

Comment: QUICK ADD ON:
I used this solution in an external typing file, but I think because only the first declaration of Characters is exported. 

There are two solututions
Export both `export interface Character` and `export namespace Character`
Then import from another file using `import { Character } from "./character.ts";`

The other solution is to not have any export keywords next to the interface or namespace declarations but `export default Character` at the end of the typing file and import it like so: `import Character from "./character.ts";`